# How to get mysqli_num_row value

Tags: php

Im learning and doing some excercises from a book, and I have an arror after a query.

I want to know the value of mysqli_num_row to further understand my error but I do not get a value.

I already check and if I put echo 'r'; I get an r in the screen so I know that line is getting executed but I can not get anything for the value of mysqli_num_row.

What should I write in the final line to get this value on the screen?

```
$q = "SELECT user_id, first_name FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')";
$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q); // Run the query.
echo mysqli_num_row($r);
```

Right now I am just getting a blank screen.

Thanks.

Comment: do an echo of $q. echo  $q = "SELECT user_id, first_name FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')";
and then run it directly in phpmyadmin. then see whether this query is running ok or not

Comment: never use `@` in front of function calls, at-least not when you are learning. Once you have learned you won't use it. the `@` will suppress any error messages you get. what if you were unable to connect, or there is an error in the query or any other errors happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using wrong function it is actually `mysqli_num_rows()`; you are missing `s` in the end of `row`

```
echo mysqli_num_rows($r);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp

Answer (score 1):

You might have skipped a letter. Try:

```
echo mysqli_num_rows($r);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to write your code like in below.

```
$q = "SELECT user_id, first_name FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')";
$r =  mysqli_query($dbc, $q); // Run the query.
echo mysqli_num_rows($r);
```

You just remove @ sign from @mysqli_query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, You have missed to add `s` in `mysqli_num_rows` it should be `mysqli_num_rows()`

```
$e =  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $e);
$p =  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $p);
$q = "SELECT user_id, first_name FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or die(mysqli_error());
echo mysqli_num_rows($r);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are learning start with prepared statements, it is much easier and less prone to injection attacks. here is a sample.

```
/* Create a new mysqli object with database connection parameters */
   $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db');

   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
      exit();
   }

   /* Create a prepared statement */
   if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT user_id, first_name FROM users WHERE email=? AND pass=SHA1(?)")) {

      /* Bind parameters
         s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
      $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $e, $p);

      /* Execute it */
      $stmt -> execute();

      /* Get num rows */
      $mum_rows = $stmt -> num_rows();

      /* Bind results */
      $stmt -> bind_result($user_id, $first_name);

      /* Fetch the value. You may need to fetch in loop if has more than 1 rows. */
      $stmt -> fetch();

      /* echo the result. */
      echo $user_id, ' = ', $first_name;

      /* Close statement */
      $stmt -> close();
   }

   /* Close connection */
   $mysqli -> close();
```

Note: error handling implementation is left to you.
This is `Object oriented style` you can use `Procedural style` also if you are not comfortable with `Object oriented style`